# Messages : Warnings / Errors

Tags: component, jerror

The official CMS 3.4 API page of Joomla classifies the JError class and all its methods as deprecated, yet I couldn't find any alternative to output messages when i.e. there is an error after server side validation for a specific component etc...
Are we meant to use those deprecated methods or are there other more recommended ways of displaying these useful error/warning messages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [enqueueMessage](https://docs.joomla.org/Display_error_messages_and_notices) to display errors, for example:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();

if ($user->guest)
{
    $msg = 'You must be logged in';
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($msg, 'error');    // red 
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($msg, 'warning');  // yellow
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($msg, 'notice');   // blue
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($msg, 'message');  // green
}
```

If you wish to store errors in logs files, you can use [JLog](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_JLog), like so:

```
jimport('joomla.log.log');

JLog::add(JText::_('JTEXT_ERROR_MESSAGE'), JLog::WARNING, 'jerror');
```

You can also use PHP exceptions to catch errors, like so:

```
// Perform a database query or something here
try
{
    // Try to get an object based on the results from the database
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    // Start crying cause it didn't work
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: that's really cool, but will the output contain any class so I can tailor the look and feel of the message box depending on the type of message? i.e. red for error, yellow for warning etc..

Comment: @MgGm - Yes, this is possible, I've updated my answer showing how to do this